# Wordpress multiple plugin options to one option as JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a plugin with multiple options, on frontend I'm using an angular app which will show all these options, so I need to save it in the DB as a JSON.

I have around 10 options, and I want all 10 to be saved in only 1 row in `wp_options` in a JSON format, currently `update_option("fee", $_POST[$key]);` saves only the last option.

```
if(array_key_exists('submit_settings', $_POST))
               {
                   foreach($global_settings->globals[0] as $key => $value)
                    {
                       update_option("fee", $_POST[$key]);
                    }
                   ?>
                       <div id="setting-error-settings-update" class="updated settings_error notice is-dismissible"> <stron> Settings have been saved. </strong> </div>
                   <?php

               }

               foreach($global_settings->globals[0] as $key => $value)
               {
                   echo '<label for='.$key.'>' . $key . '</label>';
                   echo '<input name='.$key.' value='.$value.' /> <br />';
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, each time the for loop is executed you are overwriting the option `fee`, so everytime only the last option will be saved. What you must do is to `json_enocde` the whole array and save it as a single value in the DB. When you fetch it you can `json_decode` to get all the values.

Something like this

```
$fees = [ 'one' =>'opt1', 'two' => 'opt2', 'three' => 'opt3'];

update_option("fee", json_encode($options));

// In get option
$get_options = json_decode(get_option("fee"));
```